# Using old() in Laravel

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-7

I have below code

```
<option value="{{ old('city',$user->city) }}" selected></option>
```

How to know `old()` is empty here ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the value, if value matches mark selected.

```
<option value="London" {{ old('city', $user->city) == 'London' ? 'selected' : '' }}></option>
```